# SQL Count in LEFT Joint Aggregate?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have four table like the picture bellow[image]

I want to count how many student that have **status 'v'** where in **table submission** have submission type '1' and group by **student_id** so in the last i can get table like this[image]

I have  try sql query like this

```
select p.id, (SELECT count(*) FROM  (select b.id from student as a , submission  as b WHERE a.id = b.student_id and b.id_submission_type =1  and a.status_n='v' and a.id_academic_programe = p.id GROUP BY b.student_id) )  from academic_programe as p
```

But give me error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'

Any suggestion? sory for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlations cannot be in nested subqueries.  Fortunately, this is easy to fix:

```
select p.id,
       (select count(*)
        from student st join
             submission su 
             on st.id = su.student_id and
                su.id_submission_type = 1 and
                st.status_n = 'v' and
        where st.id_academic_programe = p.id
       )
from academic_programe p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  that code is work but i want count just one student_id although they submit more than one submission. In my table submission the student can submit more than once a same type submission. Any idea how i can do that ? i want group that with student_id.

Comment: @eniac05 . . . The use `count(distinct su.student_id)` in the subquery, rather than `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
select c.academic_program_name,count(a.distinct student_name) as count
from
(select * from student where status = 'v') a
inner join
(select * from submission id_submission_type=1) b
on a.id  =b.student_id
inner join
academic_program_name c
on a.id_academic_programe = c.id
group by c.academic_program_name;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT student.id,
       student_name,
       academic_program_name AS Programe,
       COUNT( status_n ) AS status_n_count
FROM student
JOIN Submission ON student.id = Submission.student_id
RIGHT JOIN academic_program ON student.id_academic_programe = academic_program.id
WHERE id_submission_type = 1
  AND status_n = 'v'
GROUP BY student.id,
         student_name,
         academic_program_name;
```

This statement begins by joining the `student` and `Submission` so as to get a table containing the `student`'s `id`, `student_name`, `status_n` and `id_submission_type` fields.  This is then `RIGHT JOIN`ed to form a table where each academic program is listed along with each student's details, and that programs with no students are still listed.

The resulting dataset is refined as per your criteria with the `WHERE` clause, `GROUP`ed and `SELECT`ed

If you have any questions or comments then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.